# Vb.net show messagebox text and variable

Tags: sql, vb.net

Hi im new to vb and I want to display in my msgbox the text and variable but I can't seem to figure it out. My code is

```
Data = "UPDATE [Mc_Koy].[dbo].[User] SET [Balance] = [Balance] - '" & txt_fare.Text & "'WHERE [ID] = '" & txtbox_id.Text & "'"
    Command = New SqlCommand(Data, Connection)
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Dim Data1 As String = "SELECT [Balance] FROM [Mc_Koy].[dbo].[User] Where [ID] = '" & txtbox_id.Text & "'"
    Dim Command1 As New SqlCommand(Data1, Connection)
    Command1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    dr = Command1.ExecuteReader
    With dr
        .Read()
        Dim f As Double
        MsgBox("Current Balance is ", .Item(0))
        .Close()
    End With
```

But when I run it it only display the message "Current Balance is: "

Comment: Then the value is null?

Comment: No, it has value. Its value is 9994 something

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to append it to the string, so use `&`:

```
 MsgBox("Current Balance is " & .Item(0))
```

Comment: You took the words right out of my mouth - the way the sample is written, the data is being written to the title bar, not the prompt...

Comment: @Tim: not to the title bar since OP is using [`MsgBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z2azd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) not `MessageBox.Show`. It's somehow converted to a `MsgBoxStyle`. OP should switch to `Option Strict On`, but that's a different topic.

Comment: Ah, I'm thinking the old VBScript days, I think...I always forget where that second argument winds up...it's early and I haven't had enough coffee yet... ;)